# Check whether a user has installed my firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to detect if my firefox extension is installed ?

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to detect if someone browsing your website using Firefox has installed your extension, take a look at [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Adding_Events_and_Commands#Custom_events) section of the documentation.

What you can do is

- fire a custom event( say A) from your web page when it is loaded
- listen for event A from your extension and if it receives event A, fire a different event(say B) from your extension
- in your web page listen to event B. If your web page receives event B then that user has your extension installed.